# stylish form skin in visual basic .Net?

Tags: vb.net, project

How to make stylish form in VB.Net?

I am working on Final year project for graduation. Project on a "Service center" of a Mobile company.

Please suggest, how to make project more beautiful or easy user interface.

Programming language: VB.Net (2008)
Database: SQL Sever

Comment: UI Design is altogether another aspect of software development. There is no one answer to it. Use icons, images in buttons, form transparency, backgrounds etc etc.

Comment: Thanks

Aseem
 
and how can make my project with multilingual support, specially Hindi.

Comment: I think you are going too fast :)... 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119568/best-practice-to-make-a-multi-language-application-in-c-winforms

Answer (score 0):

Try using [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970268.aspx) in stead of winforms. It allows for a more stylished interface, and it's somewhat easier to build according to some.

Comment: Sad thing here in India is that Windows XP is still the most widely used OS.

Comment: Ok, i will try. 

@Aseem Gautam

please guide me. WPF not successfully work with XP?
I am beginner and need your guidance.

Thanks in Advanced.
Rahul

Answer (score 0):

Use [Krypton](http://www.componentfactory.com/) Controls which allows to style forms and controls.

Comment: Thanks,
But it is too costly.
Ok i will try with trail version.