# Create a Dialog box with local language YES NO CANCEL Options C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Im creating a project in Local langauage Hindi(Indian National Language). I need all the options to be in Hindi only. When i click on Close, there should be message box with the options like Yes, No, Cancel in Hindi Language.

My solution for this is to create a fixed sized form with labels and buttons in local language and giving return values for buttons.

Is this the correct way or is there any other method to make it bettter? 
Please suggest me a Best Solution for this!

A simple code illustration will be better!

Comment: Not sure you need to create a new dialog - you may just need to use .Net internationalization methods and make the current culture point to "hi" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001.aspx. However not tried this ever... give it a shot.

Comment: @Gishu Not much information is there in it :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best practice to make a multi language application in C#/WinForms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119568/best-practice-to-make-a-multi-language-application-in-c-winforms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check out this post: [Best practice to make a multi language application in C#/WinForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119568/best-practice-to-make-a-multi-language-application-in-c-winforms)

It Will teach you all about localisation. Have fun :)