# Advice creating language settings?

Tags: c#, globalization

Goal:
Create settings to change language in my C# application.

Problem:
Which best practice, advice, course of action, or similiar should I consider to create this functionality in order to reduce pitfall?
Please remember that the langugage can be applied in textbox, label, button etc.
Sooner or later I gonna need to add some more language in the future.

Is there any guideline to create technical languge settings in VS 2010?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best practice to make a multi language application in C#/WinForms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119568/best-practice-to-make-a-multi-language-application-in-c-winforms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond the technical advice, additionally choose a "tester" language that all programmers in the team can read/write in order to test that they've configured resources properly and programmed properly to allow for localization. I would suggest [Pig Latin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin) or something similar (or like [FaceBook's pirate english](http://www.ehow.com/how_5012370_facebook-pirate-language.html)).

Comment: +1 Great tip. I'll have to remember this when I do localization

Comment: Plus it adds a little fun for the development team!