# Manually retrieve a resource value from a resx?

Tags: c#, asp.net, resx

Is it at all possible to get the value from a resource file that is not set to the current user's culture? Our application is data-based opposed to culture-based.

e.g. a document is a French document and specific labels and fields need to be updated and replaced with new data.

Can the resource manager be instructed to use a French .resx instead of the default .resx?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [ResourceManager.GetString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsb0cfet.aspx) method and provide the desired culture as a parameter:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
var localizedString = ResourceManager.GetString("labelName", culture);
```

Comment: For future readers, to make this work, you have to create a new instance of `ResourceManager` based on your Resources. Something in the likes of `ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(typeof(YourProject.Properties.Resources))` and then call `GetString` on the new instance.

Answer (score 2):

you can set the language typeto the label text in one of the forms and then you  choose the language which one you want to show  to the end user compare with the language with that label text I.E, if the label text is french then you can show all your control names in french

**NOte:** its only works after you creating the resx file in french and rewrite manually all label and button control names in french as name value something like this..

```
  Name              value 
-----------        -------------
 lblname.text      frenchtype name 


 using System;
 using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   public form1()
   {
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new
 System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
    getlanguagaefile();
    InitializeComponent();
   }

 // blah
 // blah

private void getlanguagaefile()
{
    if (label1.Text == "French")
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new
  System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
        ComponentResourceManager resources = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Wait));
        resources.ApplyResources(this, "$this");
        applyResources(resources, this.Controls);

    }
  }
```

you can display french language  to all label texts and button texts  when the form loads

```
   private void applyResources(ComponentResourceManager resources, Control.ControlCollection controlCollection)
  {
    foreach (Control ctl in controlCollection)
    {
        resources.ApplyResources(ctl, ctl.Name);
        applyResources(resources, ctl.Controls);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do so via localization, where the resource files are adjusted to the different languages you wish to support. The following links, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119568/best-practice-to-make-a-multi-language-application-in-c-winforms) should get you what you want.

"[.NET Localization, Part 1: Resource Managers](http://www.ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/09/30/manager.html) - Check under "Creating Resources For Multiple Languages" for a good start.

[.NET Localization, Part 2: Creating Satellite Assemblies](http://www.ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/10/14/local2.htm)

[.NET Localization, Part 3: Localizing Text](http://www.ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/10/21/localpt3.htm)

[.NET Localization, Part 4: Localizing Units](http://www.ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/10/28/intlpart4.html)"