# Make a multi-language user control

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, multilingual

I'm developing a user control and now (quite at the end of the work) I'm facing the problem of making it multi-language. 
I think I could proceed in this way:

1. For UI part I could set `Localizable = true` on control and let VS generates all "records"  I need for default language.
2. Then I have to manually add all the strings I use for dynamic menus, messages and so on
3. Finally I need to create all resources file for languages I need

So using code from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984408(v=vs.71).aspx)

```
Assembly myAssembly = this.GetType().Assembly;
ResourceManager mgr = new ResourceManager("namespace.resource", myAssembly);
mgr.GetString(...)
```

my job could (easily) be done.
But I have some question:

1. When my control (generated DLL) is used from an end-user, can I have some trouble using `new ResourceManager(...)` because of main namespace changes in target app?
   Consider I don't know which namespace end-user is going to use.
2. When I create languages resources, VS generates satellite assemblies: is there a way I can "integrate" these files inside my target DLL?
   I'd like to deploy just one file if possible...
3. Is there a better way to accomplish my task?
4. Is there something I really have to care when I develop a multilaguage control?

Thanks to everybody

---

### **UPDATE:** (thanks to @lak-b for some suggestion)

I answer some question after some research:

1. It's true, I can hardcode namespace and that won't be *changed* when end-user puts my control on his form
2. Well, it seems there's not an easy way.
   Anyway [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952638/single-assembly-multi-language-windows-forms-deployment-ilmerge-and-satellite-a) provides a wonderful lesson and a great solution!!
3. ... no, for this question I'm still waiting for someone to tell me a better/easier way
4. Some critical point was specified from lak-b.
   Is there something else I have to be worried about?

Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Take a look [Best practice to make a multi language application in C#/WinForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119568/best-practice-to-make-a-multi-language-application-in-c-winforms)

1. You can to "hardcode" assembly name here.
2. Try this http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx
3. 4. You just have to goole about it and try it in action! :) In short - you have to care about a lot of things:

      - DateTime
      - Currency
      - First Day of the Week
      - Right-to-Left or Left-to-Right 
        and so on.

Comment: I'm busy now, but I'll take a look as soon as I can. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks a lot, your post gave me some idea and so I was able to find other posts/resources. Take a look at my edited post. +1 for you :)