# Build C# dll from SQL table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, dll

I have a SQL-table with three columns: Id, English and Norwegian. Id is the primary key. In my application I have a flag (EN/NO) to decide which language to use for labels, buttons ++ in the GUI.
The application is now doing a select * everytime the application loads, and the application is looking up all required values at runtime. But instead of loading the whole dataset for every instance, i want to export these values and create a dll so i can store these values locally.

Is there any possibility of creating this in-code so the dll will renew itself with every build? Or do I have to run some external program to dynamically create ex. a .cs code to copy/paste into my class? (I need to be able to re-run the process because rows will be added every time there is a need for a new label/text)

I have so far thought out three solutions on how to structure my export, but no clue on how to export the data:

1. Preserve the state of the DataTable in a static context and provide help-methods to standardize the way of getting the values out.
2. Create a class containing each unique ID as method-name, and a parameter to decide which value to return:

   ```
   public static class Names
   {
     public static string 12345(string language)
     {
       switch (language)
       {
           case "EN":
               return "Hello";
           case "NO":
               return "Hei";
           default:
               return "Hello";
       }
     }
   }
   ```
3. Create a class containing a searchable list for each language with ID as key and the value (as value)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why don't you create different resource files for different languages and load the appropriate one depending you the settings. You can do this by using [`System.Resources.ResourceManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.aspx). [This article here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5208/MultiLanguage-Applications) explains this in detail.

EDIT: Following SO post also discuss this in detail [Best practice to make a multi language application in C#/WinForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119568/best-practice-to-make-a-multi-language-application-in-c-winforms)

Answer (score 1):

No, i don't like the idea to put internationalization strings into a class library, Why you don't just use the [.NET internationalization](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43360/Globalization-Internationalization-I18N-and-Locali) feature already built in in the framework ?

Resource files are the best solution, not class library for this kind of work ...